# how to start count upto 1 until press comma(,) it should count tow

Tags: android, string

its may be silly but am confused on that this i want to start count up to one and if press comma(,)then i want to count comma only, here how i am try.

```
String conCount;

        conCount = "1";
        int countComma = conCount.length() - conCount.replace(",", "").length();
        String lenVar;
        lenVar = conCount;
        convert = String.valueOf(countComma);

        if (conCount.length() == 0) {
            lenVar = "0";

        } else {
            textViewConCount.setText(convert);

        }
```

Comment: Not able to understand your question, please elaborate.

Comment: ok, i want to count string in edit text that i got it,but i want to count comma(,)also and count shuold be one until adding comma in my editext so how can i achive it?

Comment: I don't understand you. Are you going to count commas?

Comment: Do you mean, if you got string as "abc,efg,pqr,xyz" from editText then its count should be 4 ?
and if it is not so then can you explain by giving an example like this?

Comment: ya am able to achive comma count by using replace method but here the count should start form 1 when i entered the text in edit text and its count all chart up to 1 only after enter comma count should turn 2.

Comment: Do you mean, you want comma count as well as strings count separated by comma ?

Comment: @Araju yes but here if am not adding any comma  "abcefpqrxyz" then textview count show  upto one only thats is issue

Comment: displaying count one is a problem or it should display 1 ?

Comment: string count should be one until add comma it should be 2 like that.

Comment: displaying count count one from start

Comment: can any buddy give me answer?

Comment: here my example if i entered "programming in android" then its string count 1  only and am entered comma(,)there its count start from 2, and so on means all string in edit ext should be count one only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    String editTextString = "abc,efg,pqr,xyz";

    if (editTextString.contains(",")) {
        int countStringsSeperatedByComma = 0;
        countStringsSeperatedByComma = editTextString.split(",").length;
        System.out.println("Count of strings seperated by comma : " + countStringsSeperatedByComma);

        int commaCount = countStringsSeperatedByComma - 1;
        System.out.println("Count of commas : " + commaCount);

    } else {
        System.out.println("Count of characters in editText string : " + editTextString.length());
    }
```

Output for above condition will be :

> Count of strings seperated by comma : 4
>
> Count of commas : 3

Suppose if your string is "abcefgpqrxyz" i.e. without comma then it will execute else part and print characters count as 12 in this case

> Count of characters in editText string : 12

Comment: @ashish Did you find anything useful from my answer ?

Comment: thanks for that i got the value when i start entering text the count turn into one if i did not enter comma the count it one only not count all char and count comma that is this.

Answer (score 0):

Your question statement is so ambiguous. Elaborate it completely and explain your end result with example. It's regarding string functions, I can give you the answer about it if I understand it :) :D

Comment: i want just start count from one and then count comma thats it.

Comment: like String s = "as,df,ds,a,we,f" and you want the result count = 5;

Comment: If this is the case then you can do it like this :

`String s = "ab,ac,ad,ae,af";
String[] s1 = s.split(",");
int count = s1.length - 1;`

Comment: for all stirng count should be one only and if wer enter comma ther count turn to 2

Answer (score 0):

thanks for that i got that answer like that.

```
String varStr = editextContact.getText().toString();
        //int VarCount = editextContact.getText().length();
        int countStringsSeperatedByComma = varStr.split(",").length;
        String convet=String.valueOf(countStringsSeperatedByComma);
      textViewConCount.setText(varStr);
        if (varStr.length() == 0){
            textViewConCount.setText("0");


        }else {


            textViewConCount.setText(convet);
        }
```